# Unhandled Exception Django

Tags: python, django, settings, unhandled-exception

Trying to set up a django app ([Snapboard](https://github.com/johnboxall/snapboard)) on Hostgator with FastCGI, but getting an `Unhandled Exception` error after running syncdb.

Any ideas as to why this is caused, or how to fix it, are greatly appreciated

---

Caveat:

The app is set-up to run on Django 1.0, but Django 1.3 is already installed so was trying to use that instead.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it turns out that my problem was with trying to use Hostgator for setting up django. If you have a reseller account, you are not granted root access for ssh, so I was unable to successfully run `install` and create the dependencies for the app.

I'm just going to go another route. Just letting everyone know that these difficulties exist using hostgator's 'reseller' account. Apparently, their plans that are hosted on dedicated servers are structured differently, but I had a lot of problems trying to work under a 'reseller' account structure.